# How to pass a dynamic structure from vb.net to Fortran DLL

Tags: vb.net, dll, fortran

I am having trouble passing structures or classes from vb.net to my Fortran DLL. In particular I would like to pass a structure or class which dynamic members (i.e. 1D arrays with dynamic memory allocation). I actually can pass fixed-size arrays but not dynamic ones. Any help will be highly appreciated!

For instance if I have the following structure:

```
Module Module1
<DllImport(DLL path, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Sub sub1(ByRef ppkg As Ppkg)
End Sub

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Structure Ppkg
   Dim id As Integer
   Dim arr() As Integer
End Structure

Sub Main()
    Dim pkgx As Ppkg = New Ppkg()
    sub1(pkgx)
End Sub
```

On the Fortran side:

```
module Test

type Ppkg
  integer           :: id
  integer, pointer  :: arr(:)
end type

contains

  subroutine sub1(aPpkg)
     type(Ppkg), intent(inout)   :: aPpkg         
     !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT  :: sub1
     !DEC$ATTRIBUTES STDCALL     :: sub1
     !DEC$ATTRIBUTES ALIAS       : 'sub1' :: sub1
     !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE  :: aPpkg
     ! ... do something
  end subroutine sub1

end module Test
```

When the sub1 is called from vb.net I do not have access to the members of aPpkg%arr. However, if I to use the following in the definition of the Structure or class:

```
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=4)> Dim arr() As Integer
```

and in the type definition (Fortran) I use:

```
integer :: arr(4)
```

Things work but the arrays have fixed-size not dynamic. Any help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The descriptor used for a Fortran pointer component and whatever sits being the array member of the VB struct are very unlikely to be compatible.  You are going to have to use a lower level approach, such as using a C-pointer to the array data.

Comment: How should I use C-pointers in Fortran?